# wmakerconf fails to build despite having a dependency installed

Tags: linux, debian, window-maker

I'm running Debian Jessie (testing) for AMD64 and I'm trying to build wmakerconf, and the included `configure` script won't detect the libwraster3 build headers despite them being already installed. There is no Debian package for it, so I must build it from source.

What am I missing?

Here's a quick example of what I mean:

```
black@rockshooter:~/Downloads/wmakerconf_instalacion/wmakerconf-2.12$ sudo apt-get install libwraster3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libwraster3-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
[1]+  Done                    gksu synaptic
black@rockshooter:~/Downloads/wmakerconf_instalacion/wmakerconf-2.12$ ./configurechecking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for FreeBSD system... no (Linux system found)
checking for Window Maker data directory... /usr/share/WindowMaker
checking for Window Maker sysconfig directory... missing
configure: WARNING: file 'menu' not found in /usr/etc/WindowMaker.
Use option --with-wmakeretcprefix=PFX to find Window Maker sysconfig directory
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gethostbyname in -lnsl... yes
checking for socket in -lsocket... no
checking for cos in -lm... yes
checking for get-wings-flags... no
configure: error: *** WRASTER >= 0.80.0 not installed - please install first ***
```

Answer (score 1):

`wmakerconf` was in Debian squeeze, but was removed because it was dead upstream, and had serious bugs.

See [Debian Package Tracking system - wmakerconf](http://packages.qa.debian.org/w/wmakerconf.html) and the linked bug report [RM: wmakerconf -- FTBFS;abandoned upstream](http://bugs.debian.org/658698).

I suggest if you want the package, get the Debian sources from squeeze, and try to rebuild those on jessie.